# How to declare number in typescript

Tags: typescript, angular6, angular5

I tried to declare number for attribute values but not working.How to declare it.if anyone know please help to resolve this issue.

```
let test = { 
          name:'Tree',
          type:'Land',
          attr:{
               value:Number:"12345",
               content:"test"    
          }
}
```

Attr value type should be number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing the data type statement with the assignment, if you want to have a typed json object you must create an interface or class

```
interface Test{
    name:String;
    type:String;
    attr:{
        value:Number;
        content:String;
    }
}

let test: Test = {
    name: 'Tree',
    type: 'Land',
    attr: {
        value: 12345,
        content: "test"
    }
}

let test2: Test = {
    name: 'Tree',
    type: 'Land',
    attr: {
        value: "12345", // <-- this will produce an error
        content: "test"
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't **have to** use a class, there's other options too like using [an interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) or an [inline type annotation](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-system.html#inline-type-annotation).

Comment: You're right, an interface would be a better option, I'll update the answer

Comment: I would use the typescript primitive types `string` and `number` instead of `String` and `Number`. But it's a good example, you've earn one upvote anyway.

Comment: Value some time will come as a string so on that condition how to resolve the issue?

Comment: ```value: number | string``` @NilaVaani

Answer (score 1):

It's wrong, let me fix it:

```
let test = { 
   name: 'Tree',
   type: 'Land',
   attr: {
      value: 12345,
      content: 'test'
   }
}
```

As you are initializing everything there is no need to set the types.